# Why does my server function returns a JSON Error?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am currently trying to parse my test files through a server request, I came across an issue when I run my test, it returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`.

server.ts function:

```js
app.delete('v1/admin/quiz/trash/empty', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const token = req.query.token as string;
  console.log(req.query.quizids);
  const quizids = JSON.parse(req.query.quizids as string) as number[];
  const response = adminTrashEmptyV1(token, quizids);
  if ('error' in response) {
    if (response.error === 'Token is not a valid structure.') {
      res.status(401);
    } else if (response.error === 'Provided token is valid structure, but is not for a currently logged in session.') {
      res.status(403);
    } else {
      res.status(400);
    }
  }
  return res.json(response);
});
```

testing route file (requests.ts):

```js
import request, { HttpVerb, Options } from 'sync-request';
import { port, url } from '../src/config.json';
const SERVER_URL = `${url}:${port}`;

function createRequest(method: HttpVerb, path: string, data: object) {
  let content: Options;
  if (method === 'PUT' || method === 'POST') {
    content = { json: data };
  } else {
    content = { qs: data };
  }
  const res = request(
    method,
    SERVER_URL + path,
    content
  );

  return { 
    body: JSON.parse(res.body.toString()),
    statusCode: res.statusCode
  };
}

// clear
export function requestClear() {
  return createRequest('DELETE', '/v1/clear', { });
}

export function requestTrashDelete(token: string, quizids: number[]) {
  return createRequest('DELETE', `/v1/admin/quiz/trash/empty`, { token: token, quizids: JSON.stringify (quizids) });
}
```

Terminal_1 output:

```
DELETE /v1/admin/quiz/trash/empty?token=4017954885&quizids=%5B216893084358531%2C316893084359311%5D 404 0.283 ms - 167
```

Terminal_2 output:

```
  ● /v1/admin/quiz/${quizId}/restore requestQuizRestore tests › Multiple trash delete with single token

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

      17 |
      18 |   return { 
    > 19 |     body: JSON.parse(res.body.toString()),
         |                ^
      20 |     statusCode: res.statusCode
      21 |   };
      22 | }

      at createRequest (Iteration2_test_files/requests.ts:19:16)
      at requestTrashDelete (Iteration2_test_files/requests.ts:97:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (Iteration2_test_files/clearTrash.test.ts:84:30)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       7 failed, 7 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.4 s, estimated 10 s
Ran all test suites matching /Iteration2_test_files\/clearTrash.test.ts/i.
```

So I am confused whether the issue comes from my testing route file or from my server.ts file.

I tried running it on an API client, result:

```
Cannot DELETE /v1/admin/quiz/trash/empty
```

The query data given as below:

```
http://localhost:6000/v1/admin/quiz/trash/empty?token=4017954885&quizids=%5B216893084358531%2C316893084359311
```

Comment: Because your delete route isn't responding with JSON, it's sending HTML (and almost _certainly_ a 404 page). For fun, console log your `res.body.toString()` in that test before you parse it as JSON (and by "for fun" of course I really mean "why haven't you already checked what's in that string" ;)

Comment: (Also note that Node now has `fetch` built in, so you probably want to switch to that if this is a new codebase)

Answer (score 1):

So, this is a guess, because I've never used sync-request, but based on the examples shown in that library docs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request#usage), you're trying to get the body of the request in an incorrect way:

```
body: JSON.parse(res.body.toString()),
```

You should be using something like

```
body: res.body
```

or, like in the last example of the docs there

```
body: JSON.parse(res.getBody('utf8'))
```

I would encourage you to look into that part of your code, maybe try out different alternatives (I would console log the res object and see in the console how does it look, to understand what can you do with it).

Edit: another thing you could try is to launch the server and actually send the request you're testing with postman or something like that, and see if the response you're getting is the expected one

---

Now, why is it showing the  error there? My guess is that `toString()` is an anonymous function (a function without name). I'm probably wrong, but that's the explanation I can come up right now.

---

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error details.
It points you to the right line in your test:

```
> 19 |     body: JSON.parse(res.body.toString()),
```

The most likely cause is that your server is responding with a non-JSON response, so there's nothing to parse.

First, you could try printing the response itself before trying to parse the JSON:

```
res.body.toString()
```

If the print doesn't show a JSON body, then you have your problem identified.